# Django password change:Reverse for '<function password_change_done at 0xa3b0f0c>' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

When inckuded the following in urls.py

```
(r'^settings/users/change_password/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change'
```

The following shows up on the screen,

```
Reverse for '<function password_change_done at 0xa3b0f0c>' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

And i am trying to give the access to users to change their passwords.

Whats wrong with the above code.....

Thanks........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password_change view redirects to `django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done` - this needs to be listed in your urls.py.

Alternatively, add the `post_change_redirect` argument to your password_change view to tell it where to redirect to:

```
(r'^settings/users/change_password/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'password_change_done': '/settings/users/password-changed'})
```

Also see the [relevant documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change).

Comment: I think you meant 'post_change_redirect' in that list line, in the arg dictionary.